# Decreasing a value with a named parameter doesn't change said value

Tags: c#, ms-access

I want to decrease my `urunadedi` value in an Access database. I have the following code:

```
cmd2.Connection = con;
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@urunid", Convert.ToInt64(textBox1.Text));
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hesaplam",Convert.ToInt64(textBox2.Text));
cmd2.CommandText = @"UPDATE Table1
                     SET urunadedi=urunadedi-@hesaplam
                     WHERE urunadi=@urunid";
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But the value of the field `urunadedi` is not decreasing. Why is that and how can I solve that?

---

For the benefit of non-Turkish readers, *urunadedi*, *urunid* and *urunadi* translate roughly as **ProductName**, and *hesaplam* translates roughly as **calculate**.

Comment: Is `urunadi` in the `WHERE` clause meant to be `urunadedi`?

Comment: Try swapping the order of the `Parameters.AddWithValue` statements. (Add the `@hesaplam` parameter first, then add the `@urunid` parameter.)

Comment: My brother so thanks so glad your answer so benefit really congratulations.......

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft OLEDB **ignores** parameter names and only pays attention to the *order* in which the parameters appear in the CommandText. So, for

```csharp
cmd2.CommandText = @"UPDATE Table1
                     SET urunadedi=urunadedi-@hesaplam
                     WHERE urunadi=@urunid";
```

we need to add the `@hesaplam` parameter first since it appears first in the CommandText

```csharp
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hesaplam", Convert.ToInt64(textBox2.Text));
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@urunid", Convert.ToInt64(textBox1.Text));
```

Note also that because the OLEDB parameter names are ignored it is quite common to see the question mark (`?`) being used as the parameter placeholder:

```csharp
cmd2.CommandText = @"UPDATE Table1
                     SET urunadedi=urunadedi-?
                     WHERE urunadi=?";
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Convert.ToInt64(textBox2.Text));  // @hesaplam
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Convert.ToInt64(textBox1.Text));  // @urunid
```